# Table view cell selection with slow fade away before transition

Tags: objective-c, ios

I saw in any applications that table view cell selection highlighting fades away very smoothly before transition to other view. I have searched about this topic, but I haven't find any example of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you described like so.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    double delayInSeconds = .3;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        Location *loc = [self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        LocationDetailsController *locationDetails = [[[LocationDetailsController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
        locationDetails.location = loc;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationDetails animated:YES];
    });
}
```